# Downcast reference of parent class to reference of child class in class member function

Tags: c++, casting, reference

I have a class hierarchy as below:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual Base& derived() const=0;
}

class Derived:public Base
{
    public:
    Derived& derived() const
    {
        return dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
    void test(){cout<<"Hi";}
}
```

The purpose of `derived()` is to return reference of the exact type.

```
int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base &b = d;
    (b.derived()).test();
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compile error

```
can't find void test() in Base
```

As I checked, the `Derived::derived()` did get called. It seems that `Derived::derived()` didn't return reference to derived class as expected.

Comment: Your `Base` and `Derived` has no relationship with each other.

Comment: Soory,that's a typo. Derived inherit from Base. @billz

Answer (score 0):

Did you just forget the inheritance in your sample? Something like this would work, but it's very poor design.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { }
    template < typename T>
    const T& derived() const {
        return dynamic_cast<const T&>(*this);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void test() const {std::cout<<"Hi";}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    const Base& b = d;
    b.derived<Derived>().test();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot the inheritance in the question. But Derived inherited from Base in my code. My solution did not work and I'm wondering why not.

Comment: Your solution could work. But I want to use Base& as a parameter of a function. Your solution would need to make that function a function template. I'm trying to avoid that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your solution didn't work because `Base::derived()const` returns a reference to `Base` which doesn't have a `test()` method to call.

Comment: But derived() is a virtual method. At runtime the Derived::derived() gets called.

Comment: At the point where you call `test()` you have to know that the object is really of type `Derived` so a parameter wouldn't work. Better is to use a normal override. I'll be happy to edit my code so show that if you want.

Comment: test() is called by b.derived(), which I expect to be a reference to a Derived object. Could you show me the normal override solution? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Standard override situation. I included a function as well since you said you wanted to pass the value as a parameter.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void test() const { }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void test() const {std::cout<<"Hi";}
};

void func(const Base& b) {
    b.test();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    const Base& b = d;
    b.test();
    func(b);
}
```

Comment: This a good solution. But what if I have three derived class Derived1, Derived2, Derived3 and only two of them have method test(). So I couldn't define test() in Base? I'm still curious why my solution doesn't work. b.derived() returns reference to Derived object and (b.derived()).test() should be Ok.

Comment: As long as `Base` has the `test()` method, it will work. As for your solution, look at the signature to `Base::derived()` again. What does it say it returns? It says it returns a `Base&`, not a `Derived&`.

Comment: Yes,but Base has test() would be inappropriate since it's specific to two sub classes. As for my solution, when I call b.derived(), it will call the derived() method of Derived class because b is a reference to Derived object. In Derived::derived() the object is down casted to Derived, so I'm expecting (b.derived()) should return reference to a Derived object.

Comment: I think I get it. Polymorphism is at runtime, so the compiler only sees b.derived() as Base::derived() and (b.derived()).test() won't pass compilation. Thank you very much for helping me figure it out.